# How to make side by side vertical segment in r

Tags: r, plot, line, segment

With the following data set

```
set.seed(1)
mydf=data.frame(slno=c(1:5), x1=rnorm(5),x2=rnorm(5))
> mydf
  slno         x1         x2
1    1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684
2    2  0.1836433  0.4874291
3    3 -0.8356286  0.7383247
4    4  1.5952808  0.5757814
5    5  0.3295078 -0.3053884
```

How can I make the vertical line segment for each row. I should have `5` side by side vertical line. For row `1` (`slno=1`), vertical line will start from -0.0626 to -0.82046 and so on.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ggplot2::geom_segment`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydf) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = slno, xend = slno, y = x1, yend = x2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try reshaping the data and then use `geom_line` :

```
library(tidyverse)

tidyr::pivot_longer(mydf, cols = -slno) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(slno, value, group = slno) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Same plot when resized :

[image]

Comment: If I want to reduce the gap between `slno` in the x-axis, how to do it? I expect the lines to be close to one another.

Comment: You need to resize your plot to your desired width and height. See updated plot for the same code.